# Animation CSS showing in inspector, however animation is not firing

Tags: html, css, reactjs, jsx, css-animations

I have a CSS animation that I am wanting to kick off on page load, and I would like for the components to have different delays while sliding onto the screen.

I can see that the values I have added are showing up in the CSS of the page, but when I reload the page, the animation is not getting kicked off.
[image: CSS in Google Inspector]

**Item component:**

```html
function Item(props) {
    return (
        <div
            className="ItemCard"
            style={{
                animationName: "slideIn",
                animationDelay: 100 * Math.random(4) + "ms",
                animationTimingFunction: "ease-in",
            }}>
            <img
                className="ItemPicture"
                src={props.picture}
                alt={props.name}></img>
            <p className="ItemName">{props.name}</p>
            <p className="ItemPrice">
                <strong>${props.price}</strong>
            </p>
            <a
                className="BuyNow-link"
                href={props.url}
                target="_blank"
                rel="noreferrer">
                <button className="BuyNow">Buy Now!</button>
            </a>
        </div>
    );
}
export default Item;
```

**Item.css:**

```
.ItemCard{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-basis: 15vw;
    background-color: White;
    height: 40vh;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 15px;
    align-items: center;
    overflow:hidden;
    outline: solid black 1px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 .6em .1em black;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

@keyframes slideIn {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(300px);
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(300px);
    }
}
```

Comment: Part of the issue may be a missing duration for the animation - try adding `animation-duration: 1s;`

Comment: Holy.... Well Ill be...

Comment: Looks like that solved my issue.. Ive been wracking my brain on this one for it to just be that... I appreciate it.

Comment: Ok :) I'll move it to an answer so it's clearer for others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an animation duration property to each card like so:

```css
style={{
    ...
    animation-duration: "1s",
}}
```

(moved from comment)